# How to pass a variable in gatsby graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I want to render multiple images based on the passed relative path of image for each render of the same component.
Here is my code

```
import Img from "gatsby-image";
import {useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
const TeamMemberCard = ({ name, imageSrc, bio }) => {

    const imageData=useStaticQuery(graphql`query MyQuery {
        file(relativePath: {eq: ${imageSrc}}) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              aspectRatio
              base64
              sizes
              src
              srcSet
            }
          }
        }
      }`);
```

Then in JSX, I'm using image data as:

```
    <Img fluid={imageData.file.childImageSharp.fluid} alt="nothing"/>
```

But unable to use `imageSrc` as a variable to `graphql`.

Comment: Your TypeScript snippet appears to be incomplete. Perhaps you need to add a closing `}`?

Comment: Can you please provide the error message that leads you to conclude that you're "unable to use `imageSrc` as a variable to `graphql`"?

Comment: Rather than just the offending line can you please provide the full component that includes the `<Img>` or at least a minimal version that replicates the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment, will add the complete code shortly

Answer (score 1):

This approach won't work. Please read the gatsby [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/#the-longer-answer). The only way to make your query parameterized is to add a variable to `createPage` API as described in gatsby [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/#how-to-add-query-variables-to-a-page-query)